# HashMap not returning values based on key

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to use a HashMap with my class Cell as the key. However, after putting an item into the HashMap, calling contains on the item will return false.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<Cell, String> map = new HashMap<Cell, String>();
        map.put(new Cell(0,0), "Bob");
        System.out.println(map.containsKey(new Cell(0,0)));
        System.out.println(new Cell(0,0).equals(new Cell(0,0)));
}
```

This prints out false and true, where it should print true and true, since according to the Map docs containsKey uses .equals(). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to correctly implement `hashCode()` as well.

Comment: or don't implement equals, hashCode at all. If you override equals, you should implement hashCode as well

Comment: If you don't override `hashCode()` then it will just use the default Object method which is why they are different per object despite having the same values.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(new Cell(0,0).hashCode() == new Cell(0,0).hashCode());` after all it is a HashMap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely because you don't have `equals()` and `hashCode()` implemented.  In Java, the rule of thumb is that if you implement one, you must implement the other.  In your case, it's mandatory because `HashMap` makes use of them.

You created two separate objects with two separate addresses.  Without these methods, the JVM has no way of knowing that the objects are "the same."

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Answer (score 1):

Consider how a `HashMap` is implemented. When putting, it first calculates the object `hashCode()` to figure out which bucket to place the object in. When it tries to retrieve an object, it again gets its `hashCode()`, identifies to target bucket, goes through the linked list in the bucket, calling `equals()` against each object. It returns if it finds a match.

In other words, when you use `HashMap` you need to have a correct and matching implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

The default `hashCode()` method inherited from `Object` does not correctly return the same `hashCode()` unless the object references are the same. In your case they are not.

Answer (score 0):

calling new Cell(0,0) several times produce different objects with different hash Codes. You should implement hashCode for Cell class.

Answer (score 0):

You likely forgot to implement the `hashcode()` function for `Cell`, which is also required in order to use a user defined class in a `HashMap`. Here is a simple and generally accurate way to implement a `hashcode()` function:

```
int hashcode(){
    return (field1.toString()+field2.toString()+...+fieldN.toString()).hashcode();
}
```

Where `field1` to `fieldN` are the fields in your class. If the fields are primatives (ie `int`) just take out the `toString()`.